# Android.mk Build problem with sub directories

Tags: android, makefile

I had trouble with Android.mk in PROJECT_FOLDER directory,

```
//Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

and in PROJECT_FOLDER, say there were SUB_DIR1 and SUB_DIR2

in SUB_DIR1, I had Android.mk file, but in SUB_DIR2 I did not.

And I've found out that build system doesn't go through SUB_DIR2 but SUB_DIR1,

but I am not sure why.

My guess is that my Android mk goes through every sub directory under Android.mk, searching for another Android.mk or Android.bp,

and if one directory does not have Android.mk at top, it just assumes that the directory is unrelevant?

could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: what files in the SUB_DIR2?

Comment: folders, and in side folders different modules are placed